# How do I use the DateTime.Now.ToString(); in an sql command without having to remove the slashes

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

How do I use the `DateTime.Now.ToString();` in an SQL command without having to remove the slashes. I am currently using substrings to remove the slashes, but it's becoming a bit nitty gritty because the dates can change from `12/12/2016` to `1/8/2016`.

Comment: Including your code would be helpful.

Comment: No, no, no! If you're trying to put a date value into an SQL command this way, it means you're doing things that will be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. **NEVER** using string concatenation to put data into an sql command!

Comment: Thanks I Will make sure I avoid using concatenation to put data into an sql command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the slashes? If it's because you have to use another character instead, just use `.Replace('/','-');` I would think that if you're using .NET, you won't have to convert to a string. Just pass the object as-is to the command in the `SqlParameter`.

`var param = new SqlParameter("@dateParam", SqlDbType.DateTime);`

Comment: Why not fill the Date time object directly, why to play around with the string, that's not a very good thing and can lead to potential issue

Comment: Because the field is a string I have covert it into a string before I can pass it through

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it as it is using SqlParameter. It will also prevent your database from Sql Injection.

Comment: Good point, ideal way, you may want to add more description to explain the user, one liners are generally comments